# Android IBeaconManager not connecting from activity

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, ibeacon-android

I'm using the IBeacon SDK from radius networks on the android. Im currently using the IBeaconManager in one Activity and one Service. When the app first launches, The activity binds its iBeaconManager object however `onIBeaconServiceConnect` never gets called. Calling any ranging or monitoring functions ex `startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region)` is throwing a RemoteException:

```
 The IBeaconManager is not bound to the service.  Call iBeaconManager.bind(IBeaconConsumer consumer) and wait for a callback to onIBeaconServiceConnect()
```

Surprisingly, `iBeaconMananger.isBound(myActivity)` is returning true.

Now when I start my service (unbind from my activity and bind to my service), the binding works fine and I can start monitoring for beacons. If then, I open the activity again (after unbinding from my Service and binding to my Activity), it now works in my Activity too.

So only when the app first launches, the `onIBeaconServiceConnect()` is not being called for my Activity.

any help is greatly appreciated.

---

**Update**

`MyActivity` (`BaseActivity` is a subclass of `Activity`):

```
public class MyActivity extends BaseActivity implements IBeaconConsumer {

    private IBeaconManager iBeaconManager;
    LocationManager locationManager;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_survey);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        ...

        iBeaconManager = IBeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        iBeaconManager.bind(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onIBeaconServiceConnect() {
        Log.d("mytag","beacon service connected");
        iBeaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<IBeacon> iBeacons, Region region) {
                Log.d("mytag","did range beacons");

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code for your activity?

Comment: @davidgyoung I really cant post my activity without obfuscating everything other than the iBeaconManager code. It basically is a direct implementation of the [ranging example here](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/samples.html). bind in `onCreate` and implement `onIBeaconServiceConnect()`

Comment: Just updated my question with the code

Comment: If you disable your service in the android manifest, do you get the onIBeaconServiceConnect callback?

Comment: I took out my service from the androidManifest. It still did the same thing.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see anything wrong with your code from the snippet you posted.  There must be some difference because it is so similar to the sample app, which you noted does not exhibit this behavior.  If you'd like you can zip your project to support@radiusnetworks.com and I will see if I can figure out what is going on, then report back.  Your project of course be kept confidential.

Comment: @davidgyoung unfortunately I cannot send the code over, it's the companies code and I don't have the authority to do so. However, I tried putting beaconmanager in the Application subclass and it worked fine. It must be something we're doing in the Activity life cycle that is messing if up. I will look more into it. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up moving the beaconManager to my `Application` subclass instead of using it in my activity.